# Est-ce que « suzerain » est une bonne traduction pour « overlord »?

Tags: traduction, anglais, société

Dans ma description pour [tous les autres sites Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/users/dcdecb98-f43a-4398-abc3-5095d7882464), j'ai mis:

> I work for our Stack Exchange overlords as a member of the CHAOS team.

Pour [celle de French Language and Usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/280/abby), j'ai mis:

> Je travaille sous notre suzerains Stack Exchange comme membre de l'équipe CHAOS.

Est-ce que « suzerains » est une bonne traduction pour « overlords »?

---

Mise à jour:

Sacrebleu! Quel bon assortiment de réponses! Je vais mélanger mes phrases et mots préférés. Voilà ce que j'ai fait:

> Je sers nos grands pontes de Stack Exchange comme membre de l'équipe CHAOS.

Je voulais préserver autant que possible la structure de la phrase anglaise originale, donc j'ai dû laisser passer beaucoup de suggestions excellentes. Alors, voilà. Qu'en pensez-vous?

Comment: Seems we're getting very creative with the translation. Are you sure you want us to translate, or just let our imagination shine? Once we're done, you may as well change the English one too.

Comment: Also, just checking: on your picture, you're the cat, right?

Comment: @Joubarc Right. I use a human to ferry me around from place to place.

Comment: That's what we humans are for. Don't forget to chew her hair from time to time, and use your claws to stay firmly in place if she moves too fast.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Le problème est surtout dans le "over" de "overlords".

"Suzerain" est en fait quasiment un terme technique qu'on ne trouve presque plus que dans les livres d'Histoire : les hiérarchies féodales sont tombées en désuétude en France il y a quelques siècles. Du coup, ce mot sonne mal. Son proche cousin, "souverain", pourrait mieux convenir, mais on aura du mal à le coupler avec un adjectif pour rendre le ton de la phrase initiale.

D'autres ont suggéré de bonnes alternatives proches du sens littéral. Pour s'éloigner un peu, on peut aller chercher du côté de la pègre :

> pour les caïds de StackExchange

mais ça sonne un peu vieillot aussi. Sinon on a

> pour les grands pontes de StackExchange

des *pontes* étant des personnes à hautes responsabilité, dans un langage un peu familier (mais pas irrespectueux). Avec d'autres *grands*, on a plus proche du mystique :

> pour les grands manitous de StackExchange

qui a une connotation un peu plus "sorciers", du coup plus proche du côté littérature *fantasy* de *overlords*, mais un peu vieillot. Du coup,

> pour les sorciers noirs de StackExchange

aurait une valeur plus proche du côté puissant de "overlords", mais avec une idée de malveillance de leur part, ce qui n'est pas forcément cherché. Dans ce registre sémantique, les "sorciers blancs" sont des magiciens, ou des mages et on peut sortir du schéma "grand + " en utilisant un autre adjectif :

> pour les vénérés mages de StackExchange

Enfin, pour bloucler la boucle, et revenir au "grand + " proche des termes du champ sémantique de la royauté, on a aussi en français l'expression "grand prince" qui signifie quelqu'un de bon (on dira aussi d'ailleurs "bon prince"), de généreux, de magnanime :

> pour les grands princes de StackExchange

mais on perd la notion de puissance qu'il y a dans "overlords".

Bref il y a beaucoup d'alternatives, mais aucune que je voie qui ne corresponde exactement à la phrase anglaise !

Comment: *Caïds* n'est pas vieillot, mais évoque de nos jours particulièrement les trafiquants de drogue. *Manitous* pourrait marcher, par contre *sorciers* et *mages* désignent exclusivement des magiciens et pas forcément des gens qui ont du pouvoir. *Les grands princeS*, pourquoi pas, mais les connotations ne sont pas exactment les bonnes : either good and aloof, or haughty.

Comment: ExactEment... :) Oui hein, c'est dur à traduire. (Merci pour la correction.)

Comment: J'allais dire « les grands pontes » sans hésitation, mais c'est déjà présent dans cette réponse. Donc +1.

Comment: Je trouve *sorciers noirs* parfait :p

Comment: @Evpok, j'avoue que ça aurait ma préférence s'il ne fallait pas traduire :-p

Comment: Il y a aussi _gourou_. Ou peut-être rajouter un _archi-_ devant un autre terme: _archimages_, _archimaîtres_, _archipontes_, _archipel_,... euuuh...

Comment: @Joubarc : +1 pour le préfixe "archi-" ! J'aurais dû penser à ça ! :)

Comment: Il y a aussi *[tyrans](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Tyran)* ou *[archontes](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Archonte)*.

Comment: @Joubarc, archipel ? Au [goulag](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Archipel_du_Goulag) !

Comment: @Evpok "archontes"... pas mal, okay, mais là euh... faut quand même insérer un lien vers http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/archonte **dans** la phrase de l'OP.

Answer (score 12):

[*Suzerain*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suzerain) désigne bien une sorte de chef, mais il est fortement associé à l'histoire de la [féodalité](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9odalit%C3%A9). Le suzerain est spécifiquement un chef de niveau 2, qui est juste en-dessous du chef suprême (le roi). De plus le mot est vieilli, il n'évoque pas du tout la culture contemporaine comme « *I, for one, welcome our X overlords* » peut le faire en anglais. Ce n'est donc pas une bonne traduction.

Pour traduire le ton un peu plaisant, je proposerais bien « je travaille pour nos grands maîtres de Stack Exchange » ou « pour nos maîtres suprêmes ». Et je tournerais plutôt la phrase dans l'autre sens : « je suis membre de l'équipe CHAOS, sous la direction de nos maîtres suprêmes de Stack Exchange ».

Comment: "Pour les grands anciens, qui rêvent et attendent" ? ;)

Comment: _grands maîtres_? Je sais pas, Joël a l'air plutôt petit, non?

Comment: @Joubarc, la question est « est-ce qu'il est franc-maçon ? »

Comment: Juste pour être sûr de ne pas me sentir incompris : en fait je voulais dire que pour moi _grand-maîtres_ et _grands maîtres_ n'ont pas tout à fait le même sens.

Comment: @Joubarc Ici, c'est bien un *grand maître* et pas un *maître grand* ni un *grand-maître*. Après vérification dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ma%C3%AEtre), *grand-maître* est d'usage extrêmement restreint : on l'utilise pour certains postes officiels archaïques en France, mais il n'y a pas de trait d'union dans *Grand Maître de l'ordre de Malte* ou *Grand maître d'un ensemble de loges franc-maçonnes*.

Comment: Ha, au temps pour moi.

Answer (score 8):

D'après le [online dictionary](http://onlinedictionary.datasegment.com/word/overlord), « overlord » signifie:

> a person who has general authority over others

Ca correspond assez bien à la [définition de suzerain](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/suzerain/), dans un contexte médiéval que tu suggères avec humour:

> Seigneur dont dépendaient les vassaux

(et pardon pour la source). La traduction que tu proposes est donc presque exacte: il s'agit « des suzerains de Stack Exchange», et non « du suzerain Stack Exchange », et l'emploi de « sous » n'est pas très heureux: « pour » irait mieux. Pour autant, même en modifiant cela ça ne sonne pas très bien. Je préférerais volontiers:

> J'oeuvre pour les seigneurs de Stack Exchange en tant que membre de l'équipe CHAOS.

Qu'en penses-tu ?

Answer (score 8):

I had noticed your signature and hesitated to suggest you something else, but decided it was quite fun as it was.

But since you ask, I suppose I might as well give a few suggestions of my own.

First, I feel *overlords* in this context carries an idea of mastership, so why not simply go for *maîtres*? Plus, they aim for world domination anyway, so it's fitting.

> *Je travaille pour mes maîtres de Stack Exchange en tant que membre de l'équipe CHAOS.*

As an aside I would tend to mention CHAOS first, so that what I'll do for other suggestions. You could extend *maîtres* to *grand-maîtres* (very fit to imply SE is some sort of sect) and *seigneurs*, which is already a good fit, has already been mentionned.

> *Je travaille comme membre de l'équipe CHAOS pour les seigneurs de Stack Exchange.*

You could also probably imply that you follow their orders or, more benevolently, that you follow their guidance:

> *Je travaille en tant que membre de l'équipe CHAOS sous les ordres des grand-maîtres de Stack Exchange.* (Your are somewhere between their slave and their hitman, I suppose)
>
> *Je travaille en tant que membre de l'équipe CHAOS sous la houlette des seigneurs bienfaiteurs de Stack Exchange.* (You are their grateful apprentice)
>
> *Je travaille en tant que membre de l'équipe CHAOS sour l'égide de mes protecteurs, les maîtres de Stack Exchange.* (You're under their protection)

But that's not what you asked. In any case, *suzerains* would be weird, but *souverains* is a valid alternative:

> *Je travaille pour nos souverains de Stack Exchange comme membre de l'équipe CHAOS.*

Last word I didn't change yet is "work" - that sounds so feeble, don't you think? (Not implying you don't, of course, but why not focus on the fact that you do their bidding and nothing else? Aren't you there to "serve" them?

> *Je sers nos grand-maîtres de Stack Exchange en qualité de membre de l'équipe CHAOS.*

Now, will they read that anyway?

Comment: "Je sers", c'est très bon ! "nos", par contre, n'est pas fantastique. En mixant nos réponses respectives, on aurait quelque chose comme "Je sers [les Seigneurs/les grands Maîtres] de Stack Exchange en tant que membre de l'équipe CHAOS", ce qui ne sonne pas mal du tout.

Comment: Je n'aime pas trop le _nos_ correspondant à la phrase originale non plus; je préfère _mes_ ou _les_. Mais bon.

Answer (score 6):

« Suzerain » n'a pour moi que le sens féodal -- et me choque donc ici --, « overlord » me semble plus général.  Je crois que je me passerais simplement du mot. « Seigneurs » garderait l'allusion médiévale tout en restant d'usage suffisamment courant pour ne pas choquer (au pluriel, le singulier aurait une connotation religieuse pour moi et ferait de SE un dieu).

(En passant, replace « sous » par « pour » et donne peut-être une indication sur les responsabilités de l'équipe CHAOS, ce nom risque fort de ne pas signifier grand chose pour la plupart des gens.)

Comment: Very valid point here: do not use _sous_ for _under_ as people tend to understand it literally nowadays (unless followed by a word as in _Je suis un sous-fifre des dirigeants de Stack Exchange_ which would fit). The only thing you work under is a roof. Hopefully.

Comment: @Joubarc Good to know. Could get... awkward. Merci!

Comment: @Joubarc : Even though I don't use "Je travail sous X" because I don't consider my boss to be superior in any ways, other than the corporate hierarchy, I often heard other people saying they work "sous X".

Comment: @Tipx granted, technically it's still correct, but there are quite a few places where that will elicit some grins, so better stay clear of it.

Answer (score 5):

Il y a déjà de nombreuses bonnes propositions, j'en ajoute simplement une qui n'a pas été citée mais me semblait convenir également : **hiérarques**

> Je travaille pour nos hiérarques de Stack Exchange comme membre de l'équipe CHAOS.

Answer (score 4):

J'ajoute aux autres propositions, celles-ci, dans un registre un peu plus familier : **huiles** et **grosses légumes**.

> Je sers les huiles de Stack Exchange en tant que membre de l'équipe CHAOS

ou

> Je sers les grosses légumes de Stack Exchange en tant que membre de l'équipe CHAOS

Comment: Le registre serait un peu trop familier à mon gout.